# How to monitor a bluetooth stream using Python?

Tags: python, bluetooth, serial-port

Can someone show me the simplest way to just print received bluetooth stream?

I need to verify that a computer receives data that  a mobile phone sends via bluetooth.

I have something lik this:

```
import serial
import time
import sys

port = serial.Serial('COM6', 19200, timeout=2)
while True:
    line = port.readline()
    line = line.split()
    print >>output, line
    output.flush()
```

But I am not sure if it is correct for bluetooth.

Comment: What O.S,. do you  need that for? Unless someone comes up with a Python library for covering bluetoot in a multi-platform way, O.S. specific code will be needed.  Also - no, the code for reading from the serial port won't work for bluetooth

Comment: It has to be done on ms windows[xp]

Comment: What kind of Bluetooth connection (profile) are you talking about?  RFCOMM, SPP, HFP, FTP, OBEX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PyBluez](http://code.google.com/p/pybluez/) should be enough for WindowsXP, provided you have a compatible dongle.
It has [examples](http://code.google.com/p/pybluez/wiki/Documentation#Examples) for what you need.